# PHP : Find list of X possible values which sum gives Y number

Tags: php, algorithm

I want to solve a problem but I don't know how to proceed.

In fact, I want to create the following function:

```
<?php

function xSumY(int $x, int $y)
{
  $set = [];
   
  //find $set {$a + $b + $c + ... ($x times)} which sum equal $y
}

//Examples 
$set1 = xSumY(55, 1);
$set2 = xSumY(1, 20);
$set3 = xSumY(3, 10); //returns for example {1, 3, 6}
```

**NOTE**: If possible avoid repetition of given value

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the purpose of this function? Or is this part of an assignment? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: What values might form a sum?

Comment: "I want" isn't a question. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What precisely do you need from us? To be clear, we'll help with a specific issue in some code you've tried to write, but as volunteers giving our free time, we expect some effort from you beforehand. We're not a free write-my-code service. See also [ask] and how to create a [mre] of your issue. Thanks.

Comment: It's not an assignment. I want to make a class that will allow me to spread expenses over X period

Comment: OK, so why not do: expenses divided by number of periods? Why the integer values, and all possible combination?

Comment: Okay @ADyson. I'll try to show you what I tried but it has no sense at all

Comment: @KIKOSoftware it's for simulation purpose. Also expenses must not be the same all periods

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like you need to edit the question to make the requirements 100% clear, too. Presumably you have written a specification and have a suite of unit test cases you can share?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the need for all that code you used in your answer. I made this in five minutes:

```
function xSumY(int $x, int $y)
{
    if ($y < $x) die("xSumY(): Invalid input, y < x.");
    $r = array_fill(1, $x, 1);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $y - $x; $i++) {
        $r[random_int(1, $x)]++; 
    }
    return $r;
}
```

and it seems to do the job.

Answer (score -1):

After several hours I got something like this:

```
static function xSumY(int $x, int $y)
    {
        $setOf = []; //Will contain sum subset
        $roundTo = strlen($x); //Will help to round values

        if($x < 1 || $y < 1): //return empty array if null or negative values
            return $setOf;
        elseif($x == $y): //fill with same value if $x = $y
            $setOf = array_fill(0, $x, ($x/$y));
            return $setOf;
        endif;

        $maxRand = round($y/$x, $roundTo); //we are going to find a value between 0 and this
        $multiplicator = pow((1 * 10), $roundTo+1);
        $max = $maxRand * $multiplicator;
        
        for($i=1; $i <= $x; $i++): //this loop help to create our set
            if(count($setOf) + 1 == $x):
                $currentElement = round(($y - array_sum($setOf)), $roundTo); //the last value of the set
            else:
                $currentElement = round(mt_rand(1, $max) / $multiplicator);
            endif;

            array_push($setOf, $currentElement); //add values to our set

        endfor;
        shuffle($setOf); //Make our set look more real

        while(round((min($setOf) / max($setOf)) * 100) < 20): //Reduce the difference & avoid zero
            $maxSet = max($setOf);
            $maxIndex = array_search(max($setOf), $setOf);

            $minSet = min($setOf);
            $minIndex = array_search(min($setOf), $setOf);
    
            $falsAverage = $maxSet + $minSet;
            $newMin = round((mt_rand(2, 4) / 10) * $falsAverage);
            $newMax = $falsAverage - $newMin;
            
            $setOf[$maxIndex] = $newMax;
            $setOf[$minIndex] = $newMin;
        endwhile;

        return $setOf; //Our set ready for use
    }
```

I want to know if it's good or I'm missing something or if there is a way I can dot it better. Also, I wanted to know if this operation will not excessively consume the memory.

Comment: You certainly can answer your own question, and we can comment on it, but answers are not the place to ask new questions. If you want us to review your code, post your code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Remember to properly explain what you're trying to do, which you didn't really do here.

Comment: Thank you very much for the note @KIKOSoftware and to be honest, I didn't know. So for the second platform mentioned, do I still have to register again?

Comment: @Lunar no you should be able to use the same login, registration should be a 1-click process. Go to the site while you're logged into this one, and click "join this community". Then, read their guidance, and then formulate your question. It's unclear whether this post here is intended as an Answer to your original question, or a follow-on question, it's quite ambiguous